# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression for date in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, string, excel, datetime, datetime-format

**the date in excel is of the date time format and the selected date is also date time format but wots the problem**

```
        OleDbDataAdapter da1 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [ProjectId],[ProjectName],[ManagerID],[ManagerName],[AllocationStartDate],[AllocationEndDate],[horizontalshortname] FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + @"] where [horizontalshortname]="+ "'" + TextBox_Horizontal.Text + "'" 
        + " AND [Isonsite]=" + "'" + DropDownList_Location.SelectedItem.Text + "'"
        + " AND [AllocationStartDate]>="+Calendar1.SelectedDate 
        + " AND [AllocationEndDate]<="+Calendar2.SelectedDate 
        , conn);





        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        da1.Fill(ds1);

        //if (ds.Tables[0] !=  null )
        if (ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView_Utilization_Search.Visible = true;
            GridView_Utilization_Search.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
            GridView_Utilization_Search.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            GridView_Utilization_Search.Visible = false;

        }
```

Comment: The date string should be be contained in `#` - `#some_valid_date_format#` - you should use a parametrized query - put a `'` in TextBox_Horizontal and see what the result is

Comment: After adding #some_valid_datetime_format# i donot get any rows returning..!! it is not showing error also.. it is not taking that date value with # as a different value i guess..!!

Comment: yes its working now..!! #some_valid_date_format# this is working..!!

Comment: convert to datetime and then place it in betwen # and #